# Android App Bundle: Google Play 150MB limit seems to include the Dynamic Feature Module size?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, dynamic-feature-module

Scenario:
I have an app with a lot of high res drawable images. I would like to deliver those assets with the build as opposed to via web/http/cdn.

Problem:
When uploading my .aab to google, I'm told that certain configurations will result in a build over the 150MB limit.
[image: Google Play 150MB Error]

What I've tried:

- I've extracted most of the large images to an install-time Dynamic Feature Module.
- Using bundletool, I've simulated an xxxhdpi device on arm64 with two languages. The resulting base apks do not exceed 150MB. The Dynamic Feature Module apks ("packimages-*.apk") do, but as far as I can tell, that's not only ok, but that is Google's recommended way of reducing base apk size.
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit on 150 MB is on the download size at installation time.

Since you mentioned that you configured the dynamic features to be "install-time", they will also be served at installation time and are thus counted towards the limit.

You may want to consider images that are needed at installation time (which you can leave in the base module) and images that can be downloaded at a later time (which you can put in an on-demand module) using the [Play Core SDK](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/play-feature-delivery).

Comment: I made the module on demand, but now I get this error: "The following dynamic feature modules of your App Bundle exceed the maximum size of 150 MB: packimages". It seems like all DFMs have to be under 150MB? Seems to defeat the purpose really...

Comment: Look at asset delivery instead to go beyond 150MB: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery

Comment: Asset Delivery doesn't support drawables as far as I know..